# Define index for sparse column

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, sparse-matrix

I have a table with a columns 'A' and 'B'.

'A' is a column with 90% 'null' and 10% different values , and most of the time I query to have record with one or two of these different values.

and 'B' is a column with 90% value='1' and 10% different values and most of the time I query to have record with one or two of these different values.

In this table we have DML transaction most of the time.

now , I don't know define index on these columns is good? if yes which type of index?

Comment: Are these DML done by several sessions or just one single session?

Comment: Oracle won't index values where all columns are null. So an index on `x(a)` will only contain the non-null values.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit done by several sessions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it mean that existence of null value doesn't cause any effort for oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle Bitmap Index would be the best in such situation. However, due to mulit-user environment they are not suitable - you would slow down your application significantly by table locks and perhaps get even dead-locks.

Maybe you can optimize your application by smart partitioning and usage of [Partial Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-256BA7EE-BF49-42DE-9B38-CD2480A73129.htm#VLDBG14102) (new feature in Oracle 12c)

CREATE TABLE statements below should be equivalent.

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, ... more COLUMNS)
PARTITION BY LIST (a) SUBPARTITION BY LIST (b) (
    PARTITION part_a_NULL VALUES (NULL) (
        SUBPARTITION part_a_NULL_b_1 VALUES (1) INDEXING OFF,
        SUBPARTITION part_a_NULL_b_other VALUES (DEFAULT) INDEXING ON
    ),
    PARTITION part_a_others VALUES (DEFAULT) (
        SUBPARTITION part_a_others_b_1 VALUES (1) INDEXING OFF,
        SUBPARTITION part_a_others_b_other VALUES (DEFAULT) INDEXING ON
    )   
);

CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, ... more COLUMNS)
PARTITION BY LIST (a) SUBPARTITION BY LIST (b) 
    SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
        SUBPARTITION b_1 VALUES (1) INDEXING OFF,
        SUBPARTITION b_other VALUES (DEFAULT) INDEXING ON
    )
(
    PARTITION part_a_NULL VALUES (NULL),
    PARTITION part_a_others VALUES (DEFAULT)
);

CREATE INDEX IND_A ON YOUR_TABLE (A) LOCAL INDEXING PARTIAL;
CREATE INDEX IND_B ON YOUR_TABLE (B) LOCAL INDEXING PARTIAL;
```

By this your index will consume only 10% of entire tablespace. If your WHERE condition is `WHERE A IS NULL` or `WHERE B = 1` then Oracle optimizer would skip such indexes anyway.

Verify with this query

```
SELECT table_name, partition_name, subpartition_name, indexing
FROM USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS
WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE';
```

if INDEXING is used on desired subpartitions.

**Update**

I just see actually this is an overkill because NULL values on column A do not create any index entry anyway. So, it can be simplified to

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, ... more COLUMNS)
PARTITION BY LIST (b) (
    PARTITION part_b_1 VALUES (1) INDEXING OFF,
    PARTITION part_b_other VALUES (DEFAULT) INDEXING ON
);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. what is the difference between your solution and use Filtered index ( simulate by functional index) ?

Comment: This solution creates indexes entries only where it makes sense (i.e. having low cardinality, resp. many different values) and keeps them small and efficient. With function based index like `nvl(A,'XX')` you force to create index entry for each record - no matter if it makes sense nor not.

Comment: in means that for column A , if i create index , although oracle does not use index for null , the cost of using index is same as all record has value?

Comment: It is not only "oracle does not use index for null" - NULL values do not even exist in index. Assume you have a column and all values are NULL. An index on such column has size of "0 Byte".

Comment: so , if i create simple index on column A (90% null) and in my query i have  where A="1" (any value ) , and never want to have some thing like where A IS NULL or where A IS NOT NULL , creating this index is helpful?

Comment: Yes, it helps alot. This index will be small and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have index a_b_idx on A, B (in that order):

- a) *select ... from ... where A = ...* will use index
- b) *select ... from ... where B = ...* will not use index

On the other side, if you have index b_a_idx on B, A:

- a) *select ... from ... where A = ...* will not use index
- b) *select ... from ... where B = ...* will use index

Oracle can't use second column in index if it doesn't filter on first column, since in regular cases index is tree-like structure: column1->column2->column3->etc.

You need index on column A only or on columns A, B if you do queries like a).

You need index on column B only or on columns B, A if you do queries like b).

Oracle doesn't store all-null values in index, but it can store null value for A if B contains non-null value.

Sometimes it's more fruitful to read whole table into memory and ignore index. Optimizer can do it if possible result set is big and it goes for all records, since index-to-record transition costs more than simple records read.

Also sometimes it happens erroneously for tables without statistics, so you either need jobs with *alter table ... compute statistics* or oracle 11+ that can compute statistics like this without jobs.

Most of the times, another index is good thing for queries, but bad thing for updates/disk. Each index takes disk space and each update of record(s) makes updates to every index. So for heavily updated tables it's not good to have many indexes, but for frequently queried tables it's better to have indexes covering all common cases.

For most flat queries (without joins/subqueries/hierarchy) only 1 index is used, so having indexes for each column is generally just a waste of disk space. You need multicolumn index to optimize where A=... and B=...

As for index type, you probably need simple non-unique indexes.

Comment: thanks a lot. but does your answer related to my question?!

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin - Oracle has had INDEX SKIP SCAN for quite some time now so the initial part of the answer is no longer the case. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#i51571

Answer (score 0):

- Column A

Let assume that you create an index named _columnA_index_. In general, indexes in RDBMS would not include NULL values, which means there is no index entries in _columnA_index_ pointing to records having NULL values. Thus, the following query

```
Q1: select * from MyTable where A is null;
```

will result in a table scan instead ( or DBMS opts to use another index on another column if any)

However, since there is 10% of records having 'different values', the _columnA_index_ will of course help for queries, for example.

```
Q2: select * from MyTable where A = '123';
```

In the above example, if the query returns < 1% of the records, the _columnA_index_ is helpful. Depending on how selective the query is, the index greatly improves the performance. You can create an index that is suitable for datatype of column A.

- Column B

Similarly, an index on B will not help

```
Q3: select * from MyTable where B = 1;
```

but it will help with different values

```
Q4: select * from MyTable where B = '456';
```

- NULL values

So far, I answered that any index does not help with NULL values. Therefore, if you need to query Q1 most of the time, I suggest the following ideas

- Make sure that your version of DBMS does support NULL values be included in indexes. For example Oracle 11g does but not versions before that.
- Plan to create function-based index [here](http://msutic.blogspot.se/2014/02/how-to-use-index-to-get-null-values.html), again with Oracle. But you can take the idea at least.
- **Redesign the logic of your application / your need to do querying on Null values. I prefer this approach.**

Comment: Function based index like `create index ... on ... ( nvl(A,'XX') );` would be useless (i.e. waste of space) because Oracle optimizer will skip such index anyway.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, you are quite correct but not entirely correct. You can enforce the optimizer to include the function based index into query plan or exciplitly use the function based index in the query.

Comment: In that case, the index is really helpful indeed.

Comment: Yes, but scanning an index for a value which is 90% of all values is waste of time.

Comment: > Redesign the logic of your application / your need to do querying on Null values. I prefer this approach.

Comment: "Redesign the logic of your application / your need to do querying on Null values. I prefer this approach." 
Pretty much the same thought, so I wrote it like this. Should have made it clearer.